# Is return nil, nil not idiomatic go?

Tags: go, error-handling, idioms

If we have the following method in GO:

```
GetCustomer(id string) (*Customer, error)
```

A customer for a given id may not exist in DB. When a customer is not found, the code can

```
return nil, nil
```

Is this considered bad coding practice in Go? Or would the idiomatic Go code would look like

```
 return nil, errCustomerNotFound
```

The problem I see with the second approach is that you end up checking for this specific error and handling it seperately.

Are there examples in Go source or libraries where this situation arises and one of the approaches is preferred?

*Update*

If `return nil, nil` is considered as not idiomatic. I was wondering why that is true in this case? As *Customer is a pointer, I want to return nil to indicate absence of value

Comment: A third option would be to have the signature `GetCustomer(id string) (c *Customer, ok bool, err error)` and use the return `return nil, false, nil`. This is similar to getting a key from a map in which that key may or may not exist.

Comment: Yeah sure, but is return nil, nil considered bad?

Comment: I don't think there's any problem with returning nil. I think the other two options are more explicit, but if you and your team agree on returning `nil` in these sorts of cases I think it's no problem. Or if you're writing a public library then document that you return `nil` and keep it consistent if you have any other `Get*` functions.

Comment: For this specific example, returning a "not found" error is the common sense approach. *"The problem I see with the second approach is that you end up checking for this specific error and handling it seperately."* This is not a *real* problem, there are many cases where a function can return different errors that need to be handled differently by the caller, also it is not always the case, many callers may not care that the error is specifically "not found" and just check for non-nilness.

Comment: ... If you have a case where a function's primary return value can be nil even if no error occurred, you should mention that as clearly as possible in the documentation of that function.

Comment: ... and yes, `return nil, nil` is *not* idiomatic Go.

Comment: any references for why return nil, nil is not idiomatic, would like to know why it considered not idiomatic

Comment: @MuffinTop I did not understand "distinguished primary return values" could you please explain?

Comment: Let me rephrase that:  The Go standard library does not use a sentinel value in the first return value to indicate "not found" errors. In your first example, the sentinel value is `nil`.

Comment: Why is return nil,nil not idiomatic, specifically in this case? As it is a pointer, I want to return nil to indicate absence of value

Comment: `The problem I see with the second approach is that you end up checking for this specific error and handling it seperately.` use a standard error like sql.ErrNotFound (or similar). That the not found value is a customer, is a detail useful for logging, within your code, most of the time, there should be enough context to figure out that it was a customer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whether `return nil, nil` is idiomatic in your case or not depends on whether a `nil` `*Customer` is a useful value.

If a `nil` value for `*Customer` is a normal, useful value in your code, then returning that, with no error, makes sense.

It would be rare that a nil struct pointer is useful, though--that alone could be considered non-idiomatic in most cases.

The rule to follow:

> Every function should always return a useful set of values.

In your case, where you return a struct pointer and an error, one could reasonably assume that at most one of those would be nil.

Using a nil struct pointer to indicate the absence of a value *can* be idiomatic, but not in conjunction with an error.  If your function can have only a single error condition of 'not found', you might opt for a function that returns only a single value, which may be nil, or you may opt to return a boolean indicating existence rather than an error.

But returning a nil to mean "not found" when also including an error is confusing, at best, because it violates the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: @nmdr the presence of an error indicates that the primary return value is invalid and should not be used as intended, the absence of an error, *in most cases*, will indicate the inverse. This may not always be the case but it *is* common practice, so much so that *I* would call it idiomatic. Most Go programmers, I would assume, will be used to, and rely on, this common practice to not have to double-check the primary value for nil-ness before they can use it as intended if they've already checked the error for nil, and because of that they would be tripped up by an api like yours.

Comment: Why is absence of a value an error? In my case it's not and is expected. Returning it as an error would be a bigger astonishment.

Answer (score 0):

It varies case by case, sometimes nil values are useful in cases where empty returns are frequent and useful as a zero value, where the rest of your code behaves well with them.

If nil values are uncommon and difficult to catch in testing, you should never return them at all. Also, returning a nil channel, or anything that leads to confusing nil pointer vs nil interfaces, is very heavily discouraged.

Nil channels will block on all operations instead of causing errors, often they are a sign that you should expose an API that passes read or write channels (or callbacks that wrap a send/read) to the function instead of returning channels from the function, or that you should avoid concurrency in the function and leave that to the caller.